# Compair and underline problem

Tags: android, arrays, comparison, underline

I have two array one is words another is sentences. Now, i want to underline this common word. for examples first word is "at" and first sentences is "dont at work". so I want to to display both word and sentence but in sentence was must be underline. how to make this.

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to find the word's first and last word place in whole sentence `String`, then use this code to underline that something like:

```
SpannableString content = new SpannableString("joe was a sick");
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 4, 6, spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
label.setText(content);
```

NOTE: in this example 4 and 6 are hard coded, You can find start and end points by using some looping and comparing methods upon sentence `String`

Comment: ,i am trying this, wait for response.

Comment: So what problem you are facing..?

Comment: How to search word in sentence in just like picture. or how to compare word is that present or not in sentence.

Comment: Hava a look at [this post](http://techieboycdo.blogspot.com/2010/04/check-if-string-contains-substring-in.html) or you can [Google](http://tinyurl.com/3udhrpq).

Answer (score 1):

Look at [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) and [UnderlineSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/UnderlineSpan.html). Create a `SpannableString` from your sentence, find the start and end index of each word, and set an `UnderlineSpan` with those indexes.

Comment: Nothing is changed in your question except for the pretty picture. Did you try it? If so, are there any problems? Or is your questions really about how to search for strings in your sentences?

Comment: yeah - how to search my word in sentence, but underline is solved.

Comment: That should have been a different question then. Use String.indexOf() to search for substrings.